# Empty file check on std::ofstream

Tags: c++

I've been using `std::ofstream` for writing purposes quite a bit. I open the file, do some operations based on certain conditions and close it.

Let's say that later I want to check if anything is really written into the file or not. There is not is_emtpy() kind of simple check available with `std::ofstream`.

One way I thought is of using the `stat` way which is independent of `std::ofstream`.

Wonder how do everyone else do it?

Comment: One way is to open it for reading, seek to the end, and check the position (which will equal the size of the file).

Comment: If *you* are writing to it, and you handle errors properly, then you know it already, since `write()` returns the bytes written.

Comment: Hemant, your question is already answered, check the duplicates! Next time, you can save yourself some time and search a bit before asking.. I searched for "check if file is empty c++" and got the results right away. :D Hope that helps.. :)

Comment: @gsamaras, He he. My question was to know if it could be done with std::ofstream though.

Comment: Hemant my sincere apologies. I misunderstood your question, re-opened - my intentions were good. Good luck finding an answer!

Comment: Note `tellp` just before closing?

Comment: [std::filesystem::file_size](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/file_size) could be used instead of `stat` if you are using C++17.

Answer (score 0):

Standard output streams provide a `tellp()` method which can be used to determine the current write position.  The type and meaning of the return value is implementation-defined, but for it to be useful, it must return distinct values.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ofstream out{"/tmp/test"};
    auto const empty_pos = out.tellp();

    std::clog.setf(std::ios_base::boolalpha);

    std::clog << "At start: " << (out.tellp() != empty_pos) << '\n';
    out << 'c';
    std::clog << "After writing 1 char: " << (out.tellp() != empty_pos) << '\n';
}
```

In principle, `empty_pos` may be different for each stream, so a truly portable program will take that into account.

Note also that this doesn't necessarily mean that the output is visible to other programs - use `std::flush` if that's important.